# How to select row from a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row

I have list of 10 dataframes and I want to select one row of each datafram by name.
The name of the column is name. And I want to select each row in which name=Ready.

I tried some approaches. This works, if I state the exact row number (here 2):

```
lapply(list, `[` ,c(2),)
```

But as the row number is different in the dataframes I would apply somehting like name=Ready:

```
lapply(list, `[` ,c(Ready),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` as -

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[x$name == 'Ready', ])
```

couple of other alternatives which would give the same result

```
lapply(list, subset, name == 'Ready')

#tidyverse
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(list, ~.x %>% filter(name == 'Ready'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `subset` in `base R`

```
lapply(list, subset, subset = name == 'Ready')
```